# How to load next image in the folder?

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to build a simple Image Viewer. I can load an image into a picturebox from a folder using the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "All|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png|JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|PNG Image|*.png";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName); }
    }
}
```

This simply allows me to choose an image in a folder and load it into a picturebox. Now, I would like to know if it is possible for me to make a "Next Image" button, that recognises which image I've loaded and looks for the next image in the same folder and opens it in the picturebox. Sorry if my english isn't very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce the directory of the selected file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

```
directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName);
```

Then from this directory, list all the files:

```
var files = Directory.Getfiles(directoryName)
```

Your "Next Image" button would enumerate "files"

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution.  The `button1_Click` method is the same as what you have except for the last line.  If you use this you will need to add error handling.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private AvailableImages _availableImages;

    private class AvailableImages
    {
        private List<string> _images;
        private int _selectedImage;

        public AvailableImages(IEnumerable<string> images, string selectedImage = null)
        {
            _images = images.ToList();
            _selectedImage = selectedImage == null ? 0 : _images.IndexOf(selectedImage);
        }

        public Bitmap GetNextImage()
        {
            return new Bitmap(_images[_selectedImage = ++_selectedImage >= _images.Count ? 0 : _selectedImage]);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "All|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png|JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|PNG Image|*.png";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
                _availableImages = new AvailableImages(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName)).Where(m => m.ToUpper().EndsWith("JPG") || m.ToUpper().EndsWith("BMP") || m.ToUpper().EndsWith("GIF") || m.ToUpper().EndsWith("PNG")), dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = _availableImages.GetNextImage();
    }
}
```